# Auto-importing from a local Angular library includes "public-api" and breaks application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-library

I have an Angular 7 library that is to be used by my application, both in the projects folder. When I auto-import from the compiled library, Visual Studio Code uses the path of the public api surface in the reference like so:

```
import { ModuleName } from '@org/lib/public-api';
```

and this is causing a compilation error in the application:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(9,28): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
[2]   Could not resolve @org/lib relative to [object Object]..
```

When I manually fix the import to remove the 'public-api' portion like this:

```
import { ModuleName } from '@org/lib';
```

the app recompiles and is fine. I don't think I've changed any of the default configs. This is what my tsconfig looks like in the workspace root, and my library and app tsconfigs are just the out of the box extensions that come with `ng generate`

Workspace `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@org/lib": ["dist/org-lib"],
      "@org/lib/*": ["dist/org-lib/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Has anyone run in to this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone comes across this later, the answer can be found by looking at how the angular project is set up for local development. Alongside their public_api file, they have an index.ts that just has

```
export * from './public_api';
```

This lets you cross-reference between libraries during development.